# T-SQL Execute Recursion for Each Value in Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, stored-procedures

I have a dataset with two columns. A person in the first column may be in the span of control of a person in the second column (i.e. everyone is in Michael's span of control, Dwight & Stanley are in Jim's span of control):

```
source_id     source          target_id     target        
1             Michael Scott   5             Kelly Kapoor  
3             Dwight Schrute  2             Jim Halpert
4             Stanley Hudson  2             Jim Halpert
2             Jim Halpert     5             Kelly Kapoor
```

I have a table that lists each person and their supervisor:

```
person_id       person           supervisor_id     supervisor
1               Michael Scott    0                 None
2               Jim Halpert      1                 Michael Scott
3               Dwight Schrute   2                 Jim Halpert
4               Stanley Hudson   2                 Jim Halpert
6               Ryan Howard      1                 Michael Scott
5               Kelly Kapoor     6                 Ryan Howard
```

I have a block of code that uses recursion to find a single person's span of control from the preceding table:

```
with anchor as
(
    select person_id, supervisor_id from table where unique_id = @ID
    union all
    select a.person_id, a.supervisor_id 
    from table a
    inner join Anchor b ON b.person_id = a.supervisor_id
)

select a.person_id
from anchor a
```

This block of code can be turned into a stored procedure or a function. Running it for Jim (for example), returns:

```
person_id
3 (Dwight Schrute)
4 (Stanley Hudson)
```

How do I compare each value in the initial dataset (from both the source and target columns) to the values in the column returned by the preceding block of code? In other words, for each row in `source`, I need to check if that name is within the span of control of `target`. In addition, for each row in `target`, I need to check if that name is within the span of control of `source`.

Desired End Result:

```
source_id     source          target_id     target         isEitherPersonInOther'sSOC
1             Michael Scott   5             Kelly Kapoor   Yes
3             Dwight Schrute  2             Jim Halpert    Yes
4             Stanley Hudson  2             Jim Halpert    Yes
2             Jim Halpert     5             Kelly Kapoor   No
```

I know iterations are bad (i.e. running the stored procedure for each row with a cursor or while loop). I also know `cross apply` and a function together may work, but I have been unable to figure my way through that.

Thank you for any insight you all may have!

Comment: First, i'd give each person a unique ID so you aren't' joining on names... what if you have two Jim Halperts

Comment: I have a unique ID, just used names for easier illustrative purposes.

Comment: never omit what may be relevant ;) because the solution wouldn't have assumed that

Comment: thank you - i updated it to include IDs

Comment: It does, because they are separate datasets. Source and target is a dataset of links between people - two supervisors could be linked, two people who have no span of control could be linked, etc. Alternatively, the person and supervisor table is a master table of employees of Dunder Mifflin, Scranton.

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like you need is to take your recursive CTE and output ID pairs into a temp table.  I'm picturing something like this:

```
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE cx CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT person_id FROM PersonSupervisor

CREATE TABLE #tmpPS (Supervisor int, personInChain int)

OPEN cx
FETCH NEXT FROM cx
    INTO @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    with anchor as
    (
        select person_id, supervisor_id from table where unique_id = @ID
        union all
        select a.person_id, a.supervisor_id 
        from table a
        inner join Anchor b ON b.person_id = a.supervisor_id
    )
    INSERT INTO #tmpPS
    select @id, a.person_id
    from anchor a

    FETCH NEXT FROM cx
        INTO @id
END
Close cx
Deallocate cx
```

This creates a table of all relationships, recursively expanded. Then you can output whether any given person is either above or below a given other person with this subquery. Add it to whatever query outputs your base grid:

```
SELECT
    SourceId,
    Source,
    TargetId,
    Target,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tmpPS WHERE Supervisor = SourceId and PersonInChain = TargetId)
            THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tmpPS WHERE Supervisor = TargetId and PersonInChain = SourceId)
            THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END as [isEitherPersonInOther'sSOC]
FROM ....
```

This also implies a version of this where you can separate the relationships out - If the first query, the TargetId is a subordinate of the SourceId. If the second query, then TargetId is a superior to SourceId.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a better way to do this but this is definitely one way to go about it -- note the code creates permanent tables to use in a function:

```
    create table dbo.[source]
(
    source_id  int,
    [source] nvarchar(500),
    target_id int,
    [target] nvarchar(500)
)

insert into [source]
select 1, 'Michael Scott', 5, 'Kelly Kapoor'
union all select 3,'Dwight Schrute',2,'Jim Halpert'
union all select 4 ,'Stanley Hudson',2,'Jim Halpert'
union all select 2  ,'Jim Halpert',5,'Kelly Kapoor'

create table dbo.supervisors
(
    person_id int,
    person nvarchar(500),
    supervisor_id int,
    supervisor nvarchar(500)
)

insert into dbo.supervisors
select 1,'Michael Scott', 0,'None'
union all select 2,'Jim Halpert',1,'Michael Scott'
union all select 3,'Dwight Schrute',2,'Jim Halpert'
union all select 4,'Stanley Hudson',2,'Jim Halpert'
union all select 6,'Ryan Howard',1,'Michael Scott'
union all select 5 ,'Kelly Kapoor',6,'Ryan Howard'


go


create function dbo.fn_isinspanofcontrol
(
    @sourceid int,
    @targetid int
)
RETURNS varchar(1)

as
begin

declare @retVal varchar(1)
declare @tbl table
(
    person_id int
)

;with anchor as
            (
                select person_id, supervisor_id from supervisors where person_id = @sourceid
                union all
                select a.person_id, a.supervisor_id 
                from supervisors a
                inner join Anchor b ON b.person_id = a.supervisor_id
            )
insert into @tbl
select a.person_id
from anchor a
where   
    a.person_id = @targetid

;with anchor as
            (
                select person_id, supervisor_id from supervisors where person_id = @targetid
                union all
                select a.person_id, a.supervisor_id 
                from supervisors a
                inner join Anchor b ON b.person_id = a.supervisor_id
            )
insert into @tbl
select a.person_id
from anchor a
where   
    a.person_id = @sourceid



if exists( select 1
            from @tbl 
        )
begin
    set @retVal = 'Y'
end
else
begin
    set @retVal = 'N'
end

    return @retVal

end


select 
    *, dbo.fn_isinspanofcontrol(source_id,target_id)
from [source]
```